# Please explain the details of the "Overfull \hbox" log message

Tags: fonts, font-encodings

What does the warning message

```
Overfull \hbox (1.08093pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 29--30 
[]\EU1/TimesNewRoman(1)/m/it/10 Sia $\OML/ztmcm/m/it/10 A$ 
\EU1/TimesNewRoman(1)/m/it/10 irriducibile.
```

mean? In fact, is it a warning?

Comment: There should be something else in the warning, for example `Overfull \hbox`.

Comment: You are right @egreg. Question edited. I thought they were two separate messages, because I didn't recall `Overfull \hbox`es usually being located besides `lines <foo>-<bar>` My question actually concerned the `\EU1/TimesNewRoman(1)/m/it/10` and similar, and their meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The diagnostic message accompanying an `Overfull \hbox` message always prints on the terminal and log file a representation of the box being overfull.

With

```
[]
```

TeX means omitted or unrepresentable parts. The fonts used are also shown: in your case the font used is

```
\EU1/TimesNewRoman(1)/m/it/10
```

that is the internal representation of Times New Roman probably defined with `\newfontface` or in the scope of an `\addfontfeatures` command, because of the trailing `(1)`; it would be `(0)` for a font defined with `\setmainfont` and without added features, but this is just a guess and the suffix is not readily guessable in general. The font name is always in five parts separated by slashes:

```
<encoding>/<family>/<weight>/<shape>/<size>
```

Here `EU1` is the output encoding used by XeLaTeX/`fontspec` for a font defined through `fontspec` features.

The pair of `$` symbols represent a math formula, with the font used (I guess from this you're using `mathptmx`, by the way). Then the previous font is restored and the word `irriducibile` is printed. If you used the `draft` option, the overfull would be denoted by a `|` (that corresponds to the black blob in the printout).

With the `pdftex` and `luatex` engines, also the hyphenation points would be shown, but this unfortunately can't happen with `xetex` for reasons due to a necessary change in the hyphenation mechanism.

By examining lines 29–30 in the file currently being input, you can find the problem, which can usually be solved by rewording the offending paragraph.

Comment: What's the "weight" of a font? Could the `(1)` come from `\setromanfont` or `\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}`? And yes, I am using `mathptmx`. And the solution was to adjust `\labelsep` for the theorem the problem was coming from.

Comment: @MickG The `(1)` is a suffix `fontspec` adds when two font families are based on the same font name. The weight can be medium or bold, but also light and so on.

Comment: And the "shape" is Italic or "normal". Can it be anything else?

Comment: @MickG `texdoc fntguide` is your friend